# Merge commits after changes to the branch

Tags: git

I've initially had two branches:

```
master A---B---C
                \
fork             D---E---F---H---I
```

So I wanted to get my fork branch to be merged to master at F, without merging D and E. So it becomes:

```
master A---B---C-------F---H---I
                \
fork             D---E
```

And then I would like to be able to rebase the fork to master, so it becomes:

```
master A---B---C-------F---H---I
                                \
fork                             D---E
```

(Not sure about the lettering, or should it become D' and E' and have the old ones stay after C)

So I searched around and found that I can branch my fork at "I" and then hard reset it, but it became even more complicated:

```
master A---B---C
                \
fork             D---E
                      \
to-merge               F---H---I
```

(I'm at this point now)

Please, help a noob at branching to make it work. Even it I end up with something like this:

```
master A---B---C-------F---H---I
                \     /         \
fork             D---E           D'--E'
```

I don't want to merge D and E to the master at all.

Comment: Your final goal is linearize, why not just use `git rebase -i` and rearrange that to what you need?

Comment: @J-16SDiZ I tried `git rebase -i e8a3e6d8be9afd3aa2cc47232ee5cf6dc7080ce7` from my fork branch, but that opened vim with several files (I've got spaces in my path) and after that did nothing. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: @J-16SDiZ ok. I moved the local repo to path with no spaces. As far as I can see I can pick and squash... the latter melds the commit to another. I could not understand how I can move the commits to a different branch.

Comment: @avioli: to move commit F before commit D, you just need to cut the line describing commit F, and paste it above the line describing commit D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only 3 commits, it might be simplest to just cherry-pick them into your master branch.

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick F
git cherry-pick H
git cherry-pick I
```

Comment: Thanks. I did what Blueberry suggested and found out that I need to pick them all as you suggest, not just F.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look at cherry picking.

Just a quick google brought this up.  Looks useful (and like what you need).  http://technosophos.com/content/git-cherry-picking-move-small-code-patches-across-branches

First check out master.

```
$ git checkout master
```

Then something like this for each cherry pick.

```
$ git cherry-pick F
Finished one cherry-pick.
```

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick, but the thing was that I had to pick them all, not just F.

Comment: No worries @avioli.  Yes, that would be what you'd need to do (which is why I mentioned for each cherry pick), I was just demonstrating how it would be done. :)